# Convert integer number to time format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

How can I convert an integer such as 115900 to a time? I'd like to do arithmetic operations on times so that something like: 115900 + 100 will equal 120000, rather than 11600.

Answer (score 5):

Your big problem is that an integer number does not behave like a date/time.  Since you are using Objective-C, you really should be using the NSDate class and the associated classes for formatting dates and times and managing calendars.

Start by reading the [Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtDates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000183-BCIDBADB).  That will be better than me writing it all out again.

Comment: Just as a small comment, you might want to look into such methods of NSDate as -timeIntervalSince1970, -timeIntervalSinceDate and -dateByAddingTimeInterval for the above mentioned operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int seconds = 115900 % 60; 
   int minutes = (115900 / 60) % 60; 
   int hours = 115900/ 3600; 
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i:%02i",hours, minutes, seconds]; 
   //output like is HH:MM:SS
```